# Convert string to UTF8

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8

How to convert NSString to UTF8Encode ?

My NSLog print the same result as input string

```
    NSString*  username =@"MYUSERNAME";
    username=[username stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString*  Password =@"MYUSERNAMEPASS";
    Password=[Password stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"username=%@",username);
    NSLog(@"Password=%@",Password);
```

Comment: add special character '%20' or some more like this and check again.

Comment: Do you want to add % in the string or else do you want to remove % from string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` instead of `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

```
NSString *encodeUserName = [username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

Also `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated so batter to use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` like this

```
NSString *encodeUserName = [username stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```